# Connecting a Kernel with GRUB or some other assembly bootloader

Tags: assembly, terminal, kernel, bootloader, grub

I have been following this kernel (http://www.cs.vu.nl/~herbertb/misc/writingkernels.txt) and have got down to the part where it is linked with grub. However, I do not have stage1 and stage2 in /boot/grub/ (Linux mint x64). Also when I write "mpartition -I c:" I get the error: "mpartition: init: open: No such file or directory". So it would be nice to get a link to stage1 and stage2 with all the necessary files or some code to an assembly boot loader that would load this kernel. Extra note: I used 'elf64' rather than 'elf' because of my system.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you refer to apply to GRUB v1, now referred to as GRUB legacy. Current GRUB is the project that used to be called GRUB2. They are pretty much completely different - so your instructions are no longer valid.

That said, current GRUB is a lot more flexible than GRUB legacy - perhaps you could simply use its `chainloader` functionality to load the `kernel.bin`.

Comment: Could you please give me and example of 'chainloader' to load kernel.bin.

Comment: Well, entering 'chainloader kernel.bin' on the GRUB command line would be a starting point.